# Is there a good podcast app for Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-media-center, podcasts

I would love to easily watch podcasts on my media center machine.  Is there a service or application I can run in the background which will automatically get the latest podcasts and integrate them into media center?  Even better, is there a media center application for this which has UI in MCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Media Browser](http://www.mediabrowser.tv) does podcasts, but I need to get around to re-writing the buffering portions, cause direct show buffering suck donkeys especially in Vista.

Disclaimer I manage the Media Browser project.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, but I searched far and wide, and iTunes was still the best podcast-grabbing application. The good news is you can tell it to download podcasts to a directory that Media Center will watch for updates, and you'll see them appear in your Music library.

Comment: the words "itunes" "best" and "windows" in conjunction do not sit right for me. in my opinion itunes on windows is tolerable at best.

Comment: don't I have to manually launch iTunes each time I start Windows though?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

http://thedigitallifestyle.com/csnew/tdl/b/podcast/archive/tags/Windows+Media+Center+Podcast/The+Media+Center+Show/default.aspx